# Running a JUnit4 test - from a java program

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4

I was wondering how to run some JUnit4 test inside a java program. Basically - depending on some conditions during runtime I need to decide which test runner to use. Using Junit3 I could override runTest method from TestCase class - but in JUnit4 tests do not extend TestCase class so I have nothing to override... Is there maybe some method that I need to implement... or sth else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code for you:

```
public void checkTests() throws org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError {
    checkTestClass((Class<?>) MyTestClss.class);
}

private void checkTestClass(Class<?> theClass) throws InitializationError {
    final RunNotifier notifier = new RunNotifier();
    notifier.addListener(new RunListener() {
        @Override
        public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
            Assert.fail(failure.getMessage());

        }
    });

    final Runner runner = new BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(theClass);

    runner.run(notifier);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. The problem I have is that I have to run a method (which cannot be static) before each test case... For example using JUnitCore runner. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have is that I have to run a method (which cannot be static) before each test case

If this non-static method is something related to pre-conditioning the test case, you could achieve this by annotating a method using `@Before` in you test class. Take a look at the Junit4 docs for the behavior of `@Before`.

Otherwise, to simply trigger a Junit test class, you can use the following code:

```
Runner r = 
try {
  r = new BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(Class.forName(testClass));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InitializationError e) {  // FIX if necessary: JDK 7 syntax
  // handle
}
JUnitCore c = new JUnitCore();
c.run(Request.runner(r));
```

Hope that helps.